# How i can fix this error about migration?

Tags: symfony

I try to use make:migration but i got this error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "setSchemaIgnoreClasses" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Configuration".
```

i user cache:clear but not fixed

how i can fixed this?

Comment: Funny...I got that too since today. It seems, that this function was added with doctrine/migrations v2.11. For that you need composer2, which I don't have. I use doctrine/migrations v2.10 but symfony itself is calling that function when setting up the cache container.....

Answer (score 15):

I just found out that this comes in through an update of the doctrine/doctrine-bundle to v2.7. You just need to downgrade to v2.6.4 if you're using doctrine/orm in v2.10. These two are not compatible.

If you have composer2 you can upgrade to v2.11 of doctrine/orm. That should do the trick, too.

See also:

```
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.10.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php
```

vs.

```
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.11.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php
```